# AngularJS resize to parent?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a series of LI elements in a document...they need to have their width adjusted based on number of items and width of container...how do I retrieve the width of parent container from this directive???

```
var MyApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('resize', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // TODO: Resize according to percentage of parent???
        elem.css('width', '400px');
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: Try with element.parent().width() (you should have jquery included) but may be you have to show more code

Comment: I did not use jQuery...I was under the impression that Angular would resort to it's on light weight jQL version if not used??

Comment: elem.parent()[0].offsetWidth seems to work...

Comment: If you do not want to use jQuery you will need to make two directives. One that you will place on the parent and another that you will place on the child. The parent directive will then pass its dimensions to the child's directive.

Comment: how does jQuery make a difference? i managed to ge ott to work using parent()[0].offsetWidth

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
elem.css('width', elem.parent()[0].offsetWidth);
```